# Autocomplete for angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

[image: Picture of code]

Where should I declare ng-model in the `md-autocomplete` tag of angular js material and how to store the value of it in MongoDB?

Comment: please can you show us what you have tried to do? Please try to split your question into two separate posts. One for the ng-model and one ofr saving to mongo.

Answer (score 0):

value of `"md-selected-item"` is the one your looking for, it does not return a string rather it returns your selected object. Try an example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular_material/angular_material_autocomplete.htm)
**Output** of `md-selected-item:`
example `{"value":"alabama","display":"Alabama"}` of below example.

**Where should I declare ng-model?**
You can declare your initial value to `ctrl.selectedItem`. Here i declared `self.selectedItem =  {"value":"alaska","display":"Alaska"};` to auto select a state. You can store in mongodb just by accessing object property in controller and send in post service.

```html
<html lang="en" >
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
   <script language="javascript">
        angular
           .module('firstApplication', ['ngMaterial'])
           .controller('autoCompleteController', autoCompleteController);

        function autoCompleteController ($timeout, $q, $log) {
           var self = this;
           self.simulateQuery = false;
           self.isDisabled    = false;
           // list of states to be displayed
           self.states        = loadStates();
           self.querySearch   = querySearch;
           self.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
           self.searchTextChange   = searchTextChange;
           self.selectedItem =  {"value":"alaska","display":"Alaska"};
           self.newState = newState;
           function newState(state) {
              alert("This functionality is yet to be implemented!");
           }    
           function querySearch (query) {
              var results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.states, deferred;
              if (self.simulateQuery) {
                 deferred = $q.defer();
                 $timeout(function () { 
                       deferred.resolve( results ); 
                    }, 
              Math.random() * 1000, false);
                 return deferred.promise;
              } else {
                 return results;
              }
           }
           function searchTextChange(text) {
             debugger;
              $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
           }
           function selectedItemChange(item) {
              $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
           }
           //build list of states as map of key-value pairs
           function loadStates() {
              var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
                 Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
                 Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
                 Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
                 North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
                 South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
                 Wisconsin, Wyoming';
              return allStates.split(/, +/g).map( function (state) {
                 return {
                    value: state.toLowerCase(),
                    display: state
                 };
              });
           }
           //filter function for search query
           function createFilterFor(query) {
              var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
              return function filterFn(state) {
                 return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
              };
           }
        }  
   </script>      
   </head>
   <body ng-app="firstApplication" ng-cloak>
      <div ng-controller="autoCompleteController as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak>
         
         <md-content class="md-padding">
            <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
               <p><code>md-autocomplete</code> can be used to provide search results from local or remote data sources.</p>
               <md-autocomplete
                  ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled"
                  md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
                  md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
                  md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
                  md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
                  md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
                  md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
                  md-item-text="item.display"
                  md-min-length="0"
                  placeholder="US State?">
                  <md-item-template>
                     <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
                  </md-item-template>
                  <md-not-found>
                     No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
                     <a ng-click="ctrl.newState(ctrl.searchText)">Create a new one!</a>
                  </md-not-found>
               </md-autocomplete>
               <br/>
               Output {{ctrl.selectedItem}}
            </form>
         </md-content>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```